# How do i get the variable [i] of my loop without making a function in my loop "jshint"

Tags: javascript, html

i need some help here about a script javascript for a website i assuming it's kinda obvious. 
Let me explain, i have a gallery, a loop and on every click on an image of the gallery, the clicked image will move in an other div which is for now hidden. 
So on the click i call 2 functions, the first one to show the div and the second one to change de src of the image in the hidden div by the href of the clicked image.

```
   function OnClickGallery(){ 

      var Galerie = document.getElementById('GPNPHide'), 
          liens = Galerie.getElementsByTagName('a'),
          imgkids = Galerie.getElementsByTagName('img'),
          ImageBig = document.getElementById('ImageFull'); 

        for (var i = 0 ; i < liens.length ; ++i) { 
             liens[i].onclick = function(){ 

                  GalerieVueShowToggle(); 
                  ImageBig.src = this.href; 
                  return false; 
               }; 
        } 
  } 
  window.onload=OnClickGallery;
```

Everything was working well until i tried to avoid jshint error "don't make function within a loop" by creating my function onClick outside of the loop and just calling my function in the loop but in my onClick function the i is obviously not defined here, i'm stuck here, how can i get the i of the loop in my onClick function?

```
   function onClick() {
        "use strict";
        var ImageBig = document.getElementById('ImageFull'),
            Galerie = document.getElementById('GPNPHide'),
            liens = Galerie.getElementsByTagName('a');

        ImageBig.src = liens[i].href;
        return false;
    }


    function OnClickGallery() {
        "use strict";
        var Galerie = document.getElementById('GPNPHide'),
            liens = Galerie.getElementsByTagName('a'),
            imgkids = Galerie.getElementsByTagName('img'),
            ImageBig = document.getElementById('ImageFull'),
            i;

       for (i = 0; i < liens.length; i += 1) {
            liens[i].onclick = galerieVueShowToggle;
            liens[i].onclick = onClick;
        }

    window.onload = OnClickGallery;
```

Comment: For starters, I would use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick`. To be able to help you please provide a working snippet(`HTML, CSS` too)

Comment: The "this" reference is not persistent. You should still pas this on. 
Rewrite the function function onClick() as function onClick(this) and change the onclick declaration of liens[i].onclick = onClick; to liens[i].onclick = function(){ onClick(this) };

Answer (score -1):

Pass the value of "i" to the onClick function like this:-

onClick(i)